# Weird effect in react-beautiful-dnd with Antd Table

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm using react beautiful dnd with Antd table to implement drag and drop feature.
All are working fine but I'm having the following weird effect.
[image]

This effect even happens when I drag the item and drop in its original place.
[image]

Anyone who worked with react-beautiful-dnd with Antd please help me.

Comment: where is your code? I will try it